# Hardware Malfunctioning - Display Turns on then turns off

Tags: windows-10, display, bios, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

I have a computer that has a display that as soon as the computer turns on it displays and then it ceases to display. The keyboard and the mouse still work.  The computer is a DELL Inspiron 3475 AMD A9.  What are possible underlying issues that could be causing this? I have tried getting into the BIOS and to no avail, the display turns off to run diagnostics on the computer and I have not been able to get any information about the display.  I have noticed quite a few times that the DELL Automatic Repair displays when I have the computer on, and then the display turns off.  The computer was in direct sunlight in the room it was in, and possibly an electric surge may have occurred on that side of the room. I have reasoned out that the computer could possibly need a BIOS update is my assumption correct or is the electric surge or/and sunlight toasted the computer display? Any advice or help is appreciated in any way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have noticed quite a few times that the DELL Automatic Repair
> displays when I have the computer on, and then the display turns off.

Take it to be serviced.  You seem to have a couple of serious issues:  Possibly a Drive problem and also a Display issue. They may or may not be related.

You may need a BIOS update, but in my experience with lots of computers, an older BIOS needing an update does not usually cause these issues.

You need to have a repair person diagnose the issue without you guessing (and possibly spending money on an incorrect fix).